# Adding a String to a StringList while it is part of a hashmap value

Tags: java, string, list, dictionary, hashmap

Say I have `Map<List<String>, List<String>> whatComesNext`,

And while in a for loop, for every iteration I want to add the nth element of `List<String> text` to the value of `whatComesNext`. Why can I not perform `whatComesNext.put(key, whatComesNext.get(key).add(text.get(n)))`? The idea would be to retrieve the value from its respective key in the hashmap and add my desired String to it. This is assuming that every key in the hashmap has a value.

Below is my full code:

```
static void learnFromText(Map<List<String>, List<String>> whatComesNext, List<String> text) {
    for (int i=0; i<=text.size()-3; i++) {
        if (whatComesNext.containsKey(Arrays.asList(text.get(i),text.get(i+1)))==false) {
            whatComesNext.put(Arrays.asList(text.get(i),text.get(i+1)), Arrays.asList(""));
        }

        whatComesNext.put(Arrays.asList(text.get(i),text.get(i+1)), whatComesNext.get(Arrays.asList(text.get(i),text.get(i+1))).add(text.get(i+2)));
    }
}
```

The `Arrays.asList()` looks complicated, but it's because I was getting null maps when trying to intialize my own String Lists to try and hold my keys and values, which someone told me was because I was repeatedly clearing the lists that the keys & values were assigned to, leaving them null. I thought I'd solve that problem by referring directly to the original `List<String> text`, because that remains unchanged. The idea is to first check if a key is not present in the map, and if so assign it an empty List as a value, and then add a String from `text` to the value of the map.

The error I get when running the code is `Error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>` in the line `whatComesNext.get(Arrays.asList(text.get(i),text.get(i+1))).add(text.get(i+2)));`. I don't understand where this could go wrong, because I don't see which method is returning a boolean.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Also, it's not recommended to use a mutable `Collection` as a key in a `Map`.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? A compile error? I’m not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry, added my compile error. @JacobG using a List in the HashMap is non-negotiable, since it's provided in the code given to me to work on.

Comment: add() returns a boolean. You can just do map.get(key).add(“”). There’s no need to put() again as it’s already in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that `List.add(Object o)` returns a `boolean` and not the List itself. The `Map` is declared to contain instances of `List<String>` as value. If you simply want to add a value to a list, just retrieve it from the map and call `add` on it. Check the result of the get-process for `null` and create a new list and put it into the Map if that's the case

I can see a couple of other problems as well:

- You call `Arrays.asList(...)` multiple times creating multiple lists with the same elements. This is a major performance issue and you're just lucky, that the returned list is actually implementing `equals`, so that your logic is actually working (I expected that to be the problem of your "doesn't work"-description before you updated it.
- If the key doesn't exist, you're creating a List containing an empty text. If that should be an empty list, that's not what you're doing and you might run into problems later on, when you work with text-values (that is the empty text as first element) that weren't part of the original input values.

Without changing the type of the key of the Map a - in my eyes - better implementation would look like this:

```
static void learnFromText(Map<List<String> whatComesNext, List<String>, List<String> text) {
    for (int i=0; i<= text.size() - 3; i++) {
        List<String> listKey = text.subList(i, i+2);
        List<String> value = whatComesNext.get(listKey);
        if (value == null) {
            value = new ArrayList<>();
            whatComesNext.put(listKey, value);
        }

        value.add(text.get(i+2)));
    }
}
```

The calculation of the list for the keys happens only once, increasing performance and reducing the need of resources. And I think it's more readable that way as well.

Comment: Good answer +1. The only bit I disagree with is where you say it’s lucky that Arrays.asList returns a List overriding equals. The documentation for List specifies exactly how equals must work for all implementations.

Comment: @cppbeginner To be blunt, I don't think that the Javdoc was read here to make sure that it's behaving in the way it needs to in order to let this whole thing work, so "being lucky" is still a good description in my eyes.

Comment: I suspect you’re right about the java docs not being read. I’ve just seen a real problem with your answer. Using a list returned by subList as a map key is a really bad idea. If the backing list is structurally modified the behaviour of even innocent looking methods like get(int) becomes undefined. I think for an ArrayList you get an exception thrown.

Comment: @cppbeginner `get` shouldn't be a problem but the original list must not be modified. I planned to add a comment to the source but forgot about it. To be on the safe side, you should stick with `Arrays.asList(...)`

Comment: Even that’s not safe. If the list changes, the hashCode changes and you’ll no longer be able to retrieve the value. IMHO only immutable lists should be used as map keys. Thankfully java 9 now has immutable lists.

Answer (score 1):

The **.add()** method returns a boolean, your parenthesis are misplaced, replace your last line with this one:

```
whatComesNext.put(Arrays.asList(text.get(i),text.get(i+1)), whatComesNext.get(Arrays.asList(text.get(i),text.get(i+1)))).add(text.get(i+2));
```